# TOTP Algorithm Seed Length for HmacSHA512

Tags: java, algorithm, cryptography, totp

I am trying to implement TOTTP algorithm described here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238

```
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(seed.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "HmacSHA512");
```

However RFC says that:

```
Seed for HMAC-SHA512 - 64 bytes
     String seed64 = "3132333435363738393031323334353637383930" +
     "3132333435363738393031323334353637383930" +
     "3132333435363738393031323334353637383930" +
     "31323334";
```

1. Is this `seed64` 64 bytes and what happens if I don't pass a 64 bytes seed at like I do with my key generation (my seed has an arbitrary length)?
2. Should I use Base64 encoding for my seed?

Comment: It's clear from the RFC that these example "seeds" are hex-encoded and must therefore be hex-decoded to a `byte[]` first. You can, however, achieve the same result by instead saving the ASCII string that is represented by the hex-encoded data and then using the `.getBytes()` method as you have. The ASCII string is "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234".

Comment: So, is there a problem to use a seed which is less than 64 bytes?